# The header of my website behaving differently on Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: wordpress, css, google-chrome, firefox

Why is the header of my website behaving differently on Chrome then Firefox?

On my homepage the header is flush with the background but on other pages it seems chrome invokes extra margin or padding from the top.

In Firefox everything is the same. If I make changes to the top margin of header it fixes all pages on Firefox. If I do this then in Chrome, only on the homepage, it is not correct. In Chrome all other pages are fine except the home.I'm trying to avoid having two css files.

GOOGLE CHROME Homepage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfDT0.png

FireFox Every Page & GOOGLE CHROME All other pages
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XNkE.png

```
/* CSS */



html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
      border: 0px none;
      font: inherit;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
     display: block;
}

body {
     line-height: 1;
}

body.single div.post-item p {
     font-style: normal;
}

ol, ul {
     list-style: none outside none;
}

blockquote, q {
     quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
     content: none;
}

table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0px;
}

body {
     background: url("img/header.png") repeat-x scroll center top / 100% 216px #e9e9e9;
}

.logo {
     float: left;
     height: 125px;
     margin-top: 25px;
     max-width: 569px;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;
}

.bar {
     display: inline-block;
     height: 90px;
     margin-left: 21px;
     margin-top: 32px;
     width: 540px;
}

.navigation {
     background-color: #ffa300;
     background-image: url("img/topnav.png");
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
     height: 60px;
     margin-top: 29px;
     max-width: 1130px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 1130px;
}

.header {
     margin: 0px auto;
     position: absolute; 
     left: 0; 
     right: 0;
     top: 13px;
     width: 1130px;
}

.social {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 860px;
     margin-top: -40px;
}

.social ul {
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
}

.social ul li {
     float: left;
     font-size: 22px;
     margin-top: 12px;
     padding-right: 10px;
}

.topnav {
     margin-left: 15px;
}

.topnav ul {
     overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav ul li {
     float: left;
     font-size: 22px;
     margin-top: 12px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

.topnav ul li a {
     color: #363636;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top: 5px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav ul li a:visited {
     color: #363636;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top: 5px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav ul li a:hover {
     color: grey;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top: 5px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav ul li a:active {
     color: #ffa300;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-top: 5px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav li + li:before {
     color: #d4d4d4;
     content: "|";
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     padding: 0px;
}

.subnav {
     margin-left: 15px;
}

.subnav ul li {
     float: left;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin-top: 15px;
}

.subnav ul li a {
     color: #ffffff;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-decoration: none;
     visibility: hidden;
}

.subnav li + li:before {
     color: white;
     content: "-";
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 5px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     padding: 0px;
     visibility: hidden;
}

.main {
     background-color: white;
     height: auto;
     margin: 80px auto 0px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 1130px;
}

.content {
     float: left;
     font-size: 12px;
     height: auto;
     margin: 15px;
     position: relative;
     width: 780px;
}

.titleh2 {
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     padding-top: 8px;
}

#sidebar {
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
     margin-left: 4px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     top: 15px;
     width: 300px;
}

.Secondarybox2 {
     margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.Secondarybox2 h3 {
     background: url("img/topnav.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0% #ffa300;
     border-color: lightgrey;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     color: #363636;
     font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial;
     height: 30px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-top: 10px;
}

.Secondarybox2 h3 p {
     font-size: 22px;
}

.Secondarybox2 ul {
     font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Times New Roman;
     font-size: 16px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}

.Secondarybox2 ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
     padding-top: 15px;
}

.Secondarybox2 ul li:last-child {
     padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.Secondarybox2 a {
     color: #363636;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.widget {
     border-color: lightgrey;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.widget h2 {
     background: url("img/topnav.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0% #ffa300;
     color: #363636;
     font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial;
     height: 30px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-top: 10px;
}

.widget h2 {
     font-size: 22px;
}

.widget ul {
     font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Times New Roman;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding-left: 10px;
}

.widget ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
     padding-top: 15px;
}

.widget ul li:last-child {
     padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.widget a {
     color: #363636;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.content .post-item {
     font-family: Arial;
     padding-bottom: 55px;
}

.content .post-item h2 a {
     color: black;
     font-size: 30px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.more-link {
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #ffa300;
     border: 5px none;
     color: white;
     float: left;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-left: 690px;
     margin-top: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 8px;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 10%;
}

.numComments a {
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #e1e1e1;
     border: 5px none;
     color: white;
     float: left;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-top: -43px;
     min-width: 120px;
     padding: 5px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 10%;
}

.meta {
     color: grey;
     font-size: 15px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-top: -5px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.content .post-item p {
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 25px;
     padding-top: 5px;
}

.tags a {
     color: #ffa300;
     font-size: 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.tags a:visited {
     color: #363636;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.tags a:hover {
     color: grey;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.tags a:active {
     color: #ffa300;
     text-decoration: none;
}

.bar .border {
     border-color: #161616;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     height: 84px;
     margin-top: -93px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 534px;
     z-index: 999999999;
}

.Secondarybox .streamstatus {
     clear: both;
}

.Secondarybox .streamtitleon {
     color: white;
     float: left;
     font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial;
     font-size: 58px;
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px #000000;
     width: 50px;
     z-index: 99999;
}

.Secondarybox .streamtitleoff {
     color: red;
     float: left;
     font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial;
     font-size: 58px;
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px #000000;
     width: 50px;
     z-index: 99999;
}

.Secondarybox .bgstream img {
     background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;
     clear: both;
     height: 300px;
     position: relative;
     width: 300px;
}
#morePrev a{
    background: url("img/topnav.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #ffa300;
    border-color: lightgrey;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #363636;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial;
float:left;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Montserrat-Bold"), url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/montserrat/v4/IQHow_FEYlDC4Gzy_m8fcvEr6Hm6RMS0v1dtXsGir4g.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code example showing where do you have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to div.header: 
`position: absolute;`
`left: 0;`
`right: 0;`
`top: 13px;`

And changing on div.bar: 
`margin-top: 32px;`

Comment: I made your suggested adjustments. now its Ok on google chrome for the homepage where the wordpress loop is running but not on firefox or all other pages. It seems the header for the homepage on Chrome needs to be margin-top: 14px; but on Firefox and other pages in chrome margin-top: 10px;

Comment: Add `top: 122px;` to both `div.navigation` and `div.main`.

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue. How did you troubleshoot it?

Comment: I opened the website in each browser and looked at the 'style' settings in the 'elements' panel of dev tools. It appeared you were relying on 'margin' for positioning, which can result in margin-collapsing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), so I reduced margins where needed (to equalize them), and I repositioned divs using 'top' settings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<body class='homepage'>
```

to

```
<body class='single'>
```

You have `class` as `single` on other pages but `homepage` on the main page

Comment: I added some php to try making it singe then homepage. This body class wasnt the problem. <body class'homepage'> is just what remains of my troubleshooting

Comment: Is the issue still there?